# What figure of speech is "change of mood" in Robert Frost's "Dust of Snow"?

Tags: poetry, literary-device, robert-frost

From "[Dust of Snow](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44262/dust-of-snow)" by Robert Frost:

> Has given my heart
> A change of mood
> And saved some part
> Of a day I had rued.

What figure of speech, or poetic device, is used in the line, "A change of mood"?

Comment: What makes you think it is a figure of speech?  It is just a compound noun.

Comment: @Chenmunka: I meant to say which poetic device used in this line . [ A change of mood]

Comment: @Chenmunka's comment still holds: why do you think it's a poetic device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a straightforward double meaning (ambiguity) in this line. The word “mood” can mean something internal to a person:

> **mood, *n.*, 3.a.** A person’s humour, temper, or disposition at a particular time.

or external to them:

> **mood, *n.*, 3.c.** The pervading atmosphere or tone of a particular place, event, or period.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

So we can read the line two ways: the “dust of snow” shaken down by the crow has changed the atmosphere of the place, and also changed the speaker’s feelings.

Ambiguity does not fall under the remit of “figure of speech”, which usually encompasses devices in which words are not to be taken literally. But it is an important poetic device nonetheless:

> The machinations of ambiguity are among the very roots of poetry.
>
> <sub>William Empson (1930). [*Seven Types of Ambiguity*, p. 3](https://archive.org/details/seventypesofambi0000emps_y3p0/page/2/mode/2up). London: Chatto and Windus (1947).</sub>

Comment: Can Personification  be used as  a figure of speech for this line ? "A change of mood"

Comment: So, According to you , which  figure of speech is most suitable for this line

Comment: Ambiguity: is the figure of speech here

Comment: @asr09 Why do you think ambiguity is a figure of speech?